# Can't seem to get QGIS 3.2 installed in Linux Mint - Only 2.18

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ubuntugis

I'm at the end of my rope here.  I'm trying to install QGIS 3.2 on my computer running Linux Mint 18.3 and I've gone through installing the unstable PPA and updating and upgrading half a dozen times and it just installs 2.18.  I'm supposed to be using 3.2 for a class, and I don't understand why I'm getting 2.18 when I am not using the LTR PPAs.  If someone could give me an idiot-level explanation of how to get 3.2 installed (and more important WHAT I am doing wrong), it would be a lifesaver.

Comment: Have you installed using these instructions: https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu  ?

Comment: Yes, I have added the 3.2 PPAs (the one's not marked LTR) and it doesn't matter if I use the stable or unstable version, I still end up with 2.18 getting downloaded.

Comment: If you have added only the ubuntugis-unstable ppa, you get QGIS 2.18.20. You need to add the QGIS ubuntugis xenial main repo as well. And add the signing keys for both. Please include in your question which repo and ppa lines you have added to your sources list. The output of `apt-cache policy qgis` as well. Make sure to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-cache upgrade` before. If files are held back, please report them as well.

Comment: Bingo!  Adding the QGIS ubuntugis xenial main repository did the trick.  The note on the supported distribution chart says: "5] 3.0 and above only available with ubuntugis-unstable (plain xenial lacks GDAL2)"  so I assumed that was the only repository I needed.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the QGIS ubuntugis xenial main repository did the trick. The note on the supported distribution chart says: "5] 3.0 and above only available with ubuntugis-unstable (plain xenial lacks GDAL2)" so I assumed that was the only repository I needed.